# My DNS server can be accessed outside of internet?

Tags: dns, ipv4

I'm trying to create a DNS server for
testing my Minecraft server. I read
about how DNS works. I have seen some servers like Google's and Cloudfare's but I don't understand. Do users have to set to their router my DNS server IP in order to get my mc server's IP? How does it work?

Comment: Have you already purchased a domain name, or at least looked into that part, or are you only trying to create a "private" domain? There are many introductory articles talking about how DNS servers are found for public domain names.

Comment: You first need to have a Domain Name. Buying a Domain Name usually comes with hosted DNS servers, so you would not need to set up and maintain your own DNS. Hosting your own internet-connected (authoritative) DNS server securely and reliably is non-trivial and takes technical expertise. I don't recommend it. There's always the option for DDNS (Dynamic DNS) where you don't have your own Domain Name but can define a (globally available) host name with a DDNS provider that points to your own IP address.

Comment: @StarCat if the idea is to only host a domain locally, you do not need to buy a domain name. You can already create a fake domain in your hosts file and it will work on your machine.

Comment: @LPChip, Sure, but the question is about a minecraft server, which is usually connected to the internet (although this isn't stated in the question tbh). If it's just a local service, a simple local DNS (for example BIND on a Raspberry Pi) would suffice, but all network clients would have to be set up to use this local DNS.

Comment: @StarCat I agree, but if its just for a test, they might not want to invest into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i suppose what people are trying to say is that DNS services like google are available globally, this means that anyone on the general internet can use them. simple explanation of a DNS system is a translator, you give it a name minecraft.com and it sends u back and ip address 1.1.1.1 (it is not truly translating and is more complicated. see (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rck3BALhI5c  or https://computer.howstuffworks.com/dns.htm))

a dns server you make on your home network is only available to you and those on your home network (a home pc, your phone when its on wifi etc).

if you buy a domain name from somewhere like godaddy they will tell google that when someone types in minecraft.edu it should be forwarded to the ip address 1.1.1.1 (this is not really buying a domain and is more like renting.)

a home dns does not do this for anyone not connected to your home network and is more limited. if you wanted to you could use your home ip address which you could get from https://whatismyipaddress.com/ if you give this to your friends they could connect to your minecraft server from anywhere however that would require you to open a port on your network router which i dont reccomend (for security reasons) so personally i would rent a server from somewhere like google cloud platform who offer a free year of hosting or something similar to new users.

either way you can find a lot of great tutorials on the internet.

Comment: Thank you. So I understand that I have to buy a domain :)

Comment: now worries i hope it works

Answer (score 0):

There are a few questions left open that prevents me from writing a simple answer. Luckily these questions are small and does not overcomplicate this answer.

When you talk about a minecraft server for testing, do you want to test this only on your local pc, in your entire local network? (multiple pc's inside your home) or do you want to give access to computers from the internet as well?

When it comes to minecraft or other game servers, you really do not need a domainname. You can always access the server by knowing the ip address and port.

But DNS can make it easier to connect to your server because DNS translates a name to an ip address.

For example, if you own the domain myminecraftserver.com and you set an A record to point to your public IP address, anyone on the internet can substitude the myminecraftserver.com for the ipaddress and it will work the same. Of course, ports still need to be opened on the router.

The biggest difference here in the answer is the scope. How far do you want this to reach? If you only care for your internal network, you can fake the DNS which means you don't actually need to own the domain. As your router's DNS server will first talk to whatever DNS server you assign, you can point it to a DNS server you host locally, and in there you can say: I want mydomain.com to always give 123.45.67.89 and it will work just like that.

If its only on your computer, you can just modify the hosts file, add a line in there saying

```
mydomain.com    123.45.67.89
```

and it will work just like that.

But if the whole internet needs to be able to connect to your server, then you must actually use a domain registrar to get a domain somewhere and add an A record pointing to your IP Address. You can choose to use services such as DynamicDNS that allow you to use a subdomain.domain.ext that is partially named by them, but also partially named by you that points to your ipaddress.

For example: mycooldomain.mine.nu could be one of those examples. Dyndns has a lot to choose from, but it might not be free anymore.

A Domain registrar is a webhosting service that hosts the domain itself for you. Some webhosting providers host both domains and webspace, you can use that too if you want.

Comment: I also want to test my DNS server. I want others to just type tipdytmc.com and they will join the server. But others must change their default DNS server in order to get the IP?

Comment: Then you need to buy the domain using a registrar, so it becomes available globally. Then, all goes automatic. You make the domain go to the right IP address and you and everyone else can test it as they please.

Comment: Then how it is available globally if it's a DNS server?

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems you did not fully understood my answer. A DNS server cannot create a new domain and populate it through the internet. If you want your domain to be accessible through the internet, you need to get a registration of the domain in the register, which costs money. The automated system will then transport your domain to every DNS server out there. A DNS server is only a means to handle domain queries, not to create a new domain registration. Otherwise I would create youtube.com and now everyone comes to my site instead of youtube.